# How do a prevent a click event occurring on a navigation on a another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code below works fine for my toggle menu in responsive mode. But as I go back to desktop view once I press click outside the nav bar it's slides up? How do I prevent the slide up from happening in desktop view? I only want the slide up to work in responsive mode, once the user clicks outside the menu to disappear. I've been trying find solutions to prevent this from happening, but I can't fix the problem. Please could anyone give me advice. Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('span.responsive-menu').click(function () {

 event.stopPropagation();

$('ul.nav').slideToggle(); // Toggle Menu 

}); 

$(document).click( function(){

 $('ul.nav').slideUp();

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the window width, and only apply the JS if it is on mobile:

```
$(document).click( function(){

 if($(window).width() < 1025 && $('span.responsive-menu').css("display") === "block" ) $('ul.nav').slideUp();
 //1025 will select an ipad and smaller then it. You can, of course, change the number for whatever you need

});
```

Comment: Thank for your help, that fixed my problem. Appreciated.

Comment: @AneesYaquoob no problem, glad I could help :)

Comment: I have same problem in tablet landscape and portrait view the slide up keeps happening? Do you know why this occurring?

Comment: @AneesYaquoob Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes it is, when I check it in google responsive tool to check all the devices, When I view the site in tablet mode on Kindle and Ipad,  I have problem with the nav its slide up and disappears as soon as I click outside the nav bar. I want that to stop it happening. Its works perfect anything below 750 viewpoint once i'm checking through 750, the problem occurs.

Comment: @AneesYaquoob I see your problem now, I'll update my answer.